# Dictionary<String, String> not binding in xaml (Metro App)

Tags: .net, xaml, binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've got a problem get binding working in an DataTemplate of a ListView. My binding target is a KeyValuePair. (I work with Metro App for Windows 8)

I have an Dictionary

```
Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Params.Add("Key1", "Value1");
Params.Add("Key1", "Value2");
```

I try bind it:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But KeyPairValue dont react on this (nothing bind). But if i do that binding:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I see:
[image: enter screenshot xaml binding]

Early this binding work correctly in app for Windows Phone 7. What happened in Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying `Path=`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Params}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But you might need an [`ObservableDictionary`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)

Or you may just be up against this bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/234a17ad-975f-42f6-aa91-7212deda4190 which I found by googling `clrIkeyvaluepairimpl`

Comment: i try to use ObservableDictionary or specifying Path, but it didnt help. Perhars this is a bug. :( Do you know how to resolve it for this time?

Comment: No sorry, follow the link for the bug I found.

Comment: oh, they closed bug... But no fix

Comment: Feb 2013 - Still can't bind to a dictionary, does anybody have any clean workarounds? I'm wrapping models that use dictionaries in a class that exposes them as lists :(

Comment: @Stony If the links in my answer didn't help you, try asking a new question with more detail about what you're doing in particular.

Comment: @weston Hi, using Path doesn't work, it gives the same error as if Path hadn't been used, and using ObservableDictionary means changing the underlying Model I'm using, which isn't possible, hence needing to wrap the class.

Comment: @Stony just post a new question as no-one but me and maybe iJoy are going to see these comments, so you're not going to get as much help doing this.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't so much looking for help asjust documenting the fact that the original bug still isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a List with a custom Key/Value pair instead of a Dictionary. The reason being that IEnumerable> will be used to list the Key/Value pairs present in the dictionary during binding. The problem is with KeyValuPair, not Dictionary actually, because it gets converted to System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl and there is an issue when binding to this type.

So creating a class like:

```
public class XamlFriendlyKeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue> 
{
    public TKey Key {get; set;}
    public TValue Value {get; set;} 
}
```

And using it like this should do trick:

```
Params = new List<XamlFriendlyKeyValuePair<string, string>>();
Params.Add{"Key1", "Value1"};
Params.Add{"Key1", "Value2"};
```

Source: http://www.sohuaz.xyz/questions/683779/binding-a-dictionary-to-a-winrt-listbox